# Use generic keys in dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to name keys in my dictionary in a generic way because the name will be based on the data I get from a file. I am a new beginner to Python and I am not able to solve it, hope to get answer from u guys.

For example:

```
 from collections import defaultdict

 dic = defaultdict(dict)
 dic = {}
 if cycle = fergurson:
     dic[cycle] = {}
     if loop = mourinho:
         a = 2
         dic[cycle][loop] = {a}
```

Sorry if there is syntax error or any other mistake.

The variable `fergurson` and `mourinho` will be changing due to different files that I will import later on.

So I am expecting to see my output when i type :

```
dic[fergurson][mourinho]
```

the result will be:

```
>>>dic[fergurson][mourinho]
['2']
```

It will be done by using Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found a way, if it is wrong please correct it

```
import re
dictionary={}
dsw = "I am a Geography teacher"
abc = "I am a clever student"
search = re.search(r'(?<=Geography )(.\w+)',dsw)

dictionary[search]={}
again = re.search(r'(?<=clever )(.\w+)' abc)
dictionary[search][again]={}
number = 56
dictionary[search][again]={number}
```

and so when you want to find your specific dictionary after running the program:

```
dictionary["teacher"]["student"]
```

you will get

```
>>>'56'
```

This is what i mean to

Answer (score 0):

Naming things, as they say, is one of the two hardest problems in Computer Science. That and cache invalidation and off-by-one errors.

Instead of focusing on what to call it now, think of how you're going to use the variable in your code a few lines down.

If you were to read code that was

```
for filename in directory_list:
    print filename
```

It would be easy to presume that it is printing out a list of filenames

On the other hand, if the same code had different names

```
for a in b:
    print a
```

it would be a lot less expressive as to what it is doing other than printing out a list of who knows what.

I know that this doesn't help what to call your 'dic'  variable, but I hope that it gets you on the right track to find the right one for you.